# How could an Angular/typescript developer continue collaboration with a web designer

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Once an html page has been put together it starts to acquire dependencies on Angular and typescript.

This is not ideal for the web designer who really just wants to be able to view and modify their design. Usually this involves data elements too.

In our team the designer needs to be able to continue to work with html and stylesheets; they are not a separate contracted resource.

Is there a way to set up a project so that the web designer does not need to concern themselves with npm packages, Angular versions and data sources?

---

I have since had an idea...

As it happens I am a Linux user, the designer is a Mac user.  I am wondering if it would be possible to create a project consisting of symlinks to html with typescript stubs.

---

A mock datasource might also be a viable solution.

Comment: You can use basic html page to check the design. Why should you need Angular project for that. Once you finished with your design just dump that HTML and CSS file into Angular Component.

Comment: I as a full stack/frontend developer expect to receive designs, or instructions about how something should look like. The designer or the person in charge with the visuals does not need to know what frontend technology we use on the client. They can use tools like Figma if they want to help us more and provide us with basic CSS classes and element structure and whatever. I believe it falls in the responsibility of the FE/Full stack dev to implement the design. The designer does not need to concern himself with FE technologies.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu - yes I can see that.  In our little team of 2 I need the designer to be able to continue to work on designs after I have "angularised" them.  To put it another way I need not to be full stack/frontend otherwise I just have too much to do.

Comment: @Swanand - agreed, but I need a way to enable the web designer to continue to work on designs after they hand them over.

Comment: This is a good discussion already, it is kind of zoning in on the need for a full stack role, but we cannot afford that luxury in terms of time, plus, the web designer is so much more talented than I.

Comment: you can use storybook for implementing individual components that have the functionality behind them. Then work with individual pages as HOC's. More of a bottom up approach, but will eventually freeze the scope. On the other hand, the template HTML strings can be actually linked to different HTML nodes while parsing. This would add to the build time but can help in distributing the work